# String Resources with Shared Project and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I'm trying to put all my string resources in one place. I have created a Shared Project in Visual Studio called `MySolution.Shared` which contains my string resources file, i.e.,

`MySolution.Shared/Strings/en-US/Resources.resw`

In that file I have defined a single string with key `MyKey` and value `MyString`. I have then added a reference to this Shared Project to a Universal Apps project called `MySolution.Universal`.

Using `<TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" x:Uid="MyKey"/>` in XAML neither shows anything nor throws an exception. Using `MyTextBlock.Text = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("MyKey")` in code behind does work.

So, how do I correctly reference shared string resources in a Shared Project directly from XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that WPF doesn't know which property of "MyTextBlock" should the value of "MyKey" be assigned to.

So you need to change the key of "MyKey" to "MyKey.Text".
this means that any element with the x:Uid="MyKey" should have its text property set to "MyString".

It is mostly useful for Localizable UI's and when you want to set RTL or LTR flow direction of elements, or their fonts, etc...

example:
 (in resources)

```
<data name="Inputs.FontFamily" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Segoe UI</value> </data>
```

and in xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Uid="Inputs" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"/>
```

Comment: Perfect. Understand now.